# Unable to add Firebase Crashlytics for Gradle version 7.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, android-gradle-7.0

Unable to add Firebase Crashlytics dependencies/classpath in Android for Gradle 7.2

Where should I write.

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0'
```

I successfully mapped Google services as.

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'    
    //to
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
```

Getting following error if I map Crashlytics classpath

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crashlytics-gradle', version: '2.9.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crashlytics-gradle:com.google.firebase.firebase-crashlytics-gradle.gradle.plugin:2.9.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
    BintrayJCenter
    maven(https://jitpack.io)
```

Project level Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
    // below line has a problem
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crashlytics-gradle' version '2.9.0' apply false

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {

}
```

Gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Thu May 12 10:12:33 PKT 2022
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
rootProject.name = "Video Player"
include ':app'
```

I had searched a lot before posting this question but didn't find something useful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The documentation is not updated for the new Android project structure yet.

In your project level `build.gradle` you need to add this:

```
buildscript {
  //other things....
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.0'
  }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
  id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
  id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.10" apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Then in your app level `build.gradle` at the start you need to add the plugin

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
  id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
```

and then in the same file add the Crashlytics dependencies to the corresponding block:

```
dependencies {
   //... other dependencies
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

Answer (score 35):

Add this inside the **root project**'s `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.1' apply false
    .... some other plugins
}
```

Next, add this inside the **app module**'s `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    .... some others plugins
}
```

Finally, add this inside the **app module**'s `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    ... some other dependencies
}
```

Now, force a crash in your app something like this:

```
throw RuntimeException("Crashlytics Test")
```

Check your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

Done!

Comment: Great, that was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, @Williaan, do you have a general instruction on how to go from "classpath" approach to the newer "plugins only" way? There a lots of integration instructions using the old way and I would use the new one everywhere to be consistent. For example, know I am trying to add OSS Licenses Gradle Plugin this way ( https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/blob/master/oss-licenses-plugin/README.md ) - any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You should use like this

```
   id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.2' apply false
```

Comment: Where do you found it? I do not want to open  a question for every plugin in my classpath.

Comment: Thank you! Firebase should update their documentation on this

Answer (score 5):

In your project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    ext.crashlytics_version = '2.9.1'
}

plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version "$crashlytics_version" apply false
}
```

Then in your app's build.gradle, apply the plugin:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
```

Comment: This should accepted as the correct answer to work with gradle .kts file

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to let Android Studio add it for you.

Make sure you remove all code from previous attempts to add it and then:

**Tools -> Firebase -> Crashlytics -> Get started with Firebase Crashlytics**

There should be a button that will add the needed code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Kotlin libraries, even if you're on Java:

```
...
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
...
```