# Unable to add Firebase Performance Plugin for the new Android gradle project structure

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-performance, android-gradle-7.0

I'm trying to add to my Firbebase Performance to my Android project, but [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android?hl=pt-br#add-perfmon-plugin) does not explain how to add the classpath on the new gradle.

Where should I write.

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
```

... I tried to mapped to:

```
id "com.google.firebase.perf-plugin" version "1.4.2" apply false
```

I had searched a lot before posting this question but didn't find something useful.

It seems that the firebase documentations are not updated, because I see the same problems with other tools like [Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542162/unable-to-add-firebase-crashlytics-for-gradle-version-7-2) and [Google Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964599/how-can-i-add-google-services-classpath-for-firebase-in-build-gradle-of-new-andr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' version "1.4.2" apply false
```

Thanks [Chat GPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat)!! :D

[image: Chat GPT showing how to do it]

Comment: That's right :) And the documentation has been updated to show this new Gradle syntax.